# VB open specific Excel Version when two are installed

Tags: excel, autohotkey, vba

I am looking at this piece of code that I got from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic31923.html) because I would like to use it.  The issue is, I have used 2003 to create the "test.xls" file but when I run this code it opens in 2007.  Is there any way to force this to open in a specific Excel version rather than the default?

```
GoSub, GuiOpen
pweb := COM_AtlAxCreateControl(WinExist(), A_Temp . "\test.xls")
pxlb := COM_Invoke(pweb, "Document")      ; Excel Workbook
pxls := COM_Invoke(pxlb, "Worksheets", 1)   ; Excel Worksheet
Return

GuiOpen:
Gui, +Resize +LastFound
Gui, Show, w800 h600 Center, Excel
COM_AtlAxWinInit()
Return
GuiClose:
Gui, Destroy
COM_Invoke(pxlb, "Save")
COM_Release(pxls)
COM_Release(pxlb)
COM_Release(pweb)
COM_AtlAxWinTerm()
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way that file is associated on windows...try this on an open folder:

> Tools > Folder Options > FileTypes

Look for the xls file and change which program opens it. If you dont find it simply add it and change its options accordingly.

Comment: The extension is assigned correctly, if I double click the file it opens with 2003 and when I double click xlsx files they open with 2007.  It's when I try to open it programmatically that causes the issue.  It's not only with opening files either, if I want to create an Excel.Application object it will always create a 2007, I can't get it to open an Excel.Application object in 2003.